# Disable favicon.ico request in wordpress based site

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I'm using twentytwentytwo theme. When I open the page, it performs 2 requests to `favicon.ico`. How can I completely disable favicon.ico request in wordpress based site? Do we have any htaccess setting for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

all it means is that people with browsers that use favicon (Internet Explorer 5.0 +, Firefox, Opera and a most others) are visiting your site. While seeing a 404 in your log files usually means that a visitor got the dreaded "404 Page Not Found" error, in this case it doesn't. All it means is that the default icon was shown instead of a custom one, your visitors saw no errors :-)

This is the easiest to do and it will show your icon no matter what page your visitor adds to their favorites. Simply upload your new icon to the main directory of your site, ie. [www.example.com/favicon.ico](http://www.example.com/favicon.ico).

Thank You